# How does Spark handle Timestamp types during Pandas dataframe conversion?

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pandas dataframe with timestamp columns of type pandas.tslib.Timestamp. I looked through the pyspark source code from 'createDataFrame'([link to source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/d492cc5a21cd67b3999b85d97f5c41c3734b1ba3/python/pyspark/sql/session.py#L515)) and it seems that they convert the data to a numpy record array to a list:

```
data = [r.tolist() for r in data.to_records(index=False)]
```

However, timestamp types get converted in this process to a list of longs:

```
> df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start=datetime.datetime.now(),periods=5,freq='s'))
> df
0 2017-07-25 11:53:29.353923
1 2017-07-25 11:53:30.353923
2 2017-07-25 11:53:31.353923
3 2017-07-25 11:53:32.353923
4 2017-07-25 11:53:33.353923
> df.to_records(index=False).tolist()
[(1500983799614193000L,), (1500983800614193000L,), (1500983801614193000L,), (1500983802614193000L,), (1500983803614193000L,)]
```

Now if I pass such a list to a RDD, do some operations(not touching the timestamp column) and then call

```
> spark.createDataFrame(rdd,schema) // with schema mentioning that column as TimestampType
TypeError: TimestampType can not accept object 1465197332112000000L in type <type 'long'>
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What should I do(before converting the list to a RDD) to preserve the datetime type.

**Edit 1**

A few methods I'm aware of that will involve post dataframe creation processing are:

1. Add timezone information to datetime object in pandas. However this seems unnecessary and can lead to errors depending on your own timezone.
2. Convert the long to a timestamp using the datetime library.

> Assuming tstampl is the input:  tstamp = datetime(1970, 1, 1) +
>   timedelta(microseconds=tstampl/1000)

3. Convert the datetime to string on Pandas dataframe side, then cast to datetime on Spark dataframe side.

> As explained in Suresh's answer below

**However I'm looking for a simpler way which would take care of all processing before dataframe creation itself.**

Answer (score 2):

I tried by converting the timestamp column to string type and then apply tolist() on pandas series. Use the list in spark dataframe and convert back to timestamp there.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start=datetime.datetime.now(),periods=5,freq='s'))
>>> df
                    0
0 2017-07-25 21:51:53.963
1 2017-07-25 21:51:54.963
2 2017-07-25 21:51:55.963
3 2017-07-25 21:51:56.963
4 2017-07-25 21:51:57.963

>>> df1 = df[0].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
>>> type(df1)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
>>> df1.tolist()
['2017-07-25 21:51:53', '2017-07-25 21:51:54', '2017-07-25 21:51:55', '2017-07-25 21:51:56', '2017-07-25 21:51:57']

 from pyspark.sql.types import StringType,TimestampType
 >>> sdf = spark.createDataFrame(df1.tolist(),StringType())
 >>> sdf.printSchema()
 root
    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 >>> sdf = sdf.select(sdf['value'].cast('timestamp'))
 >>> sdf.printSchema()
 root
    |-- value: timestamp (nullable = true)

 >>> sdf.show(5,False)
 +---------------------+
 |value                |
 +---------------------+
 |2017-07-25 21:51:53.0|
 |2017-07-25 21:51:54.0|
 |2017-07-25 21:51:55.0|
 |2017-07-25 21:51:56.0|
 |2017-07-25 21:51:57.0|
 +---------------------+
```

Comment: Yup, I'm aware of this method and 1 more method involving Long to timestamp reconversion(currently what I'm using) too. Problem is all these methods require some sort of post dataframe conversion processing. Which is what I'm hoping to avoid.

Comment: Are you doing Long to timestamp conversion in spark using /1000000000 and casting to Timestamp ??

Comment: nope. Assuming tstampl is the input:  tstamp = datetime(1970, 1, 1) + timedelta(microseconds=tstampl/1000)

Comment: I'll add in the edit - I'm really hoping for a more efficient answer